# View storage devices in Windows 8?

Tags: usb, windows-8-preview

I just installed the Windows 8 preview.  Is there a way to view my USB devices without going into Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Two options here:

- Right click in the bottom left, click on `Device Manager`.
- Go to the Start Screen, type `Devices`, click on `Settings`, click on `Devices`.

Comment: Like it, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

No with the apps that are pre-installed in Windows, but I don't know if there's one in the Store that you can browse your files in the USB device.

I know that with many apps you can work with files stored in your USB device.

Comment: He doesn't want to browse his files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) which does the following:

> USBDeview is a small utility **that lists all USB devices that currently connected to your computer**, as well as all USB devices that you previously used. 
>   For each USB device, extended information is displayed: Device name/description, device type, serial number (for mass storage devices), the date/time that device was added, VendorID, ProductID, and more... 
>   USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB devices that you previously used, disconnect USB devices that are currently connected to your computer, as well as to disable and enable USB devices. 
>   You can also use USBDeview on a remote computer, as long as you login to that computer with admin user.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the product here, and provide the link for reference.